# Git pushes to too many branches

Tags: git, github, version-control, branch

I have several branches: `master`, `develop`, `feature1`, `feature2`.

I have developed some stuff in `feature1` and `feature2` (and pushed). Then I switched to `master`, done some changes and pushed:

```
% git push
To git@github.acme.com:ossmgt/myrepo.git
 ! [rejected]        feature1      -> feature1      (non-fast-forward)
 ! [rejected]        feature2      -> feature2      (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.acme.com:ossmgt/myrepo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. If you did not intend to push that branch, you may want to
hint: specify branches to push or set the 'push.default' configuration
hint: variable to 'current' or 'upstream' to push only the current branch.
```

I have verified on our local ACME Github instance that changes to `master` were pushed. But git seems to get an idea that once I pushed to `feature1` and `feature2` I still want to push those branches even if I switched to another branch, e.g. `master`. Config:

```
% git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@github.acme.com:ossmgt/myrepo.git
  Push  URL: git@github.acme.com:ossmgt/myrepo.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    develop          tracked
    master           tracked
    feature1         tracked
    feature2         tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    master           merges with remote master
    feature1         merges with remote feature1     
    feature2         merges with remote feature2         
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    develop          pushes to develop          (up to date)
    master           pushes to master           (up to date)
    feature1         pushes to feature1         (local out of date)
    feature2         pushes to feature2         (local out of date)
```

It seems to be harmless, but it's annoying. How can I configure git to push to CURRENT (checked out) branch only?

Comment: You are using an older version of Git, <1.9 I would guess?  Git has changed this specific behavior recently so you might want to review the changes to the defaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
git config --global push.default current
```

This will configure git to only push the current branch.
See http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config for more info.